# Can't Create lists and Survey in Quick Launch Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, launch

I have a SharePoint site and made several quick launches by going in SiteActions -> SiteSettings -> in Look and Feel Chose Quick Launch (i'm using SharePoint 2007). After that, I wanted to add List in one of them (lets say Launch #2). I click on Launch #2 and then create, after that I created lists. The thing is that this list goes under Launch #1 and not under Launch #2.
Is there anything that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the new link to the list, you have to specify in which quick link zone the link to the list should appear.

The last field on the new link form is used for this.